# Unknown component ID: authClientCollection

Tags: php, yii2

I'm doing my site like this tutorial, https://www.mushtaqtahir.com/blog/2/facebook-authentication-using-yii2-authclient, but when I'm trying to go to my `localhost/basic/web/index.php` I have that error:

```
Invalid Configuration – yii\base\InvalidConfigException

Unknown component ID: authClientCollection
```

in `basic\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\ServiceLocator.php`.

Maybe it's a problem in my config. I haven't in my config folder `main.php` file and I create it and add data like in tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check in you `basic/config/web.php` and add in component section the requiredc params

```
'components' => [
    'authClientCollection' => [
      'class' => 'yii\authclient\Collection',
      'clients' => [
        'facebook' => [
          'class' => 'yii\authclient\clients\Facebook',
          'authUrl' => 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?display=popup',
          'clientId' => 'YOUR APP CLIENT ID',
          'clientSecret' => 'YOUR APP CLIENT SECRET',
          'attributeNames' => ['name', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name'],
        ],
      ],
    ],
.....
],
```